# How to push and deploy local image to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have started to learn kubernetes. So, I have installed minikube, and I don't know how to push my local builded image to kubernetes. I'm doing next:

```
minikube start 
eval $(minikube docker-env) 
docker build -t some_image
```

But when I run docker images, there isn't my image. So can you help me, how to push and deploy my local docker image?

Answer (score 2):

Answer shared by @fatcook is good reference point, a simpler solution would be.

Before building the docker image just execute : `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

It will export following variables.

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/username/.minikube/certs"
export DOCKER_API_VERSION="x.yy"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Now you can build images `docker build` and it will be available on minikube instance.

It's a simple dirty way to go.

Comment: Ok, i have tried, but when i run kubectl get pods, my pod status is CrashLoopBackOff

Comment: It's means that for some reason, your container is starting and then crashing off. Try doing `kubectl logs pod-name` and `kubectl describe pod pod-name` and see the reason for crashing pod.

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case was the use of :latest in the yaml. Apparently latest is a kind of reserved word. If for a version I was using static :1.0 for example all was working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a local docker registry which minikube can use to pull images from.
Check this link https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615 which provides detailed explanation of how this can be achieved.

You can also set your own [registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/#why-use-it) and use it in your yamls to pull images. Just tag your images with something like `localhost:5000/your-image-name` and push them before running your pod on minikube